# Stack column table with Flex-box

Tags: css, flexbox

My question is about flex-box.  I have a  based table that I'm trying to add flex-box to.  The table is 4 columns wide and I'm trying to stack the columns in pairs when the screen is a mobile device.

I've been trying to mess with the codes but I can't figure out where to add the flex CSS inputs to achieve this.

Here's my goal:

Desktop:

```
A1   B1   C1   D1
a2   b2   c2   d2
a3   b3   c3   d3
```

Mobile:

```
A1   B1
a2   b2
a3   b3
C1   D1
c2   d2
c3   d3
```

Here's my current code

```
<style>
  div.packages {
     font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
     border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     border-collapse: collapse;
     }
 .divTable.packages .divTableCell, .divTable.packages .divTableHead {
     border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
     padding: 3px 2px;
     }
 .divTable.packages .divTableBody .divTableCell {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #656565;
    }
 .divTable.packages .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
    background: #EFEFEF;
    }
 .divTable.packages .divTableHeading {
    }
 .divTable.packages .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF8700;
    text-align: center;
    }
  .packages .tableFootStyle {
    font-size: 13px;
    }
  .packages .tableFootStyle .links {
    text-align: right;
    }
  .packages .tableFootStyle .links a{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #A40808;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
 .packages.outerTableFooter {
    border-top: none;
    }
 .packages.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
    padding: 3px 5px; 
    }
/* DivTable.com */
 .divTable{ display: table; }
 .divTableRow { display: table-row; }
 .divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
 .divTableCell, .divTableHead { display: table-cell;}
 .divTableHeading { display: table-header-group;}
 .divTableFoot { display: table-footer-group;}
 .divTableBody { display: table-row-group;}
 </style>



 <div class="divTableHeading">
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableHead">head1</div>
 <div class="divTableHead">head2</div>
 <div class="divTableHead">head3</div>
 <div class="divTableHead">head4</div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="divTableBody">
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableCell">cell1_1</div><div class="divTableCell">cell2_1</div><div class="divTableCell">cell3_1</div><div class="divTableCell">cell4_1</div></div>
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableCell">cell1_2</div><div class="divTableCell">cell2_2</div><div class="divTableCell">cell3_2</div><div class="divTableCell">cell4_2</div></div>
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableCell">cell1_3</div><div class="divTableCell">cell2_3</div><div class="divTableCell">cell3_3</div><div class="divTableCell">cell4_3</div></div>
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableCell">cell1_4</div><div class="divTableCell">cell2_4</div><div class="divTableCell">cell3_4</div><div class="divTableCell">cell4_4</div></div>
 <div class="divTableRow">
 <div class="divTableCell">cell1_5</div><div class="divTableCell">cell2_5</div><div class="divTableCell">cell3_5</div><div class="divTableCell">cell4_5</div></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you can achieve that behaviour through `table` properties it's unnecessarily complicated. Using `flexbox + list items` is a much more simple and efficient way to do it.

You can make a list for each column and group them in flex containers to achieve the desired behaviour. You can change the properties of elements depending on screen size through `media-queries`. I have made a demo for you down below. When the screen size is less than 600px the column containers are not flex anymore so they wrap. Resize your browser to see how it changes.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
}
#column-1-2 {
    display: flex;
}
#column-3-4 {
    display: flex;
}
.column ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #column-3-4, #column-1-2 {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="column-1-2">
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column-3-4">
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  a baseline on setting up the flex-box. thanks so much!